# does virtualbox uses a network of 169.254.176.18/17?

Tags: virtualbox, comodo-firewall

My comodo firewall allerts me about a LAN network in the above ip range, however my system is running on wifi with no Lan connected so what can this be ? 
There are no virtualboxes running.

Comment: if you are just asking whether you can tell that VBox is running somewhere on your network, just because you see this warning, then the answer is no; most modern OSes will fall back to zero conf addressing if configured for DHCP but no server could be contacted.

Answer (score 2):

The 169.254.x.x address range is known as the [link local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) address range.  It used in "zero configuration" setups where no DHCP server can be found.  Each member of the local network will choose an IP address from the range (that doesn't conflict with anyone else). It is designed for cases where only the local network needs to communicate and no DHCP is available.

This is your exact situation, most likely an unused interface such as the virtualbox one.  There is little risk in using this range, it would never be routed.  Your alternative is to assign static addresses to network interfaces.

Comment: But i dont understand i dont of a cable connected i only use Wifi, where then does this network come from ?, is a neighbours windows 7 PC over wifi ??

Comment: This network is locally set by the operating system, not remotely.

Answer (score 0):

well i used ipconfig and it does seam to be related a virtual network card from virtualbox, see below

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network: 

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::152:894d:6afb:b012%22
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.176.18
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```